# How can I show an image with its original resolution using template_icon() method?

Tags: python, scripting

I have a `template_icon()` UI inside a box UI.

Since I am using `template_icon()` UI to show an image, its resolution looks compressed just like an icon.

I'm trying to show an image with its original resolution.

I could not adjust the resolution with size parameter in method.

```
            imagePreviewBox.template_icon(
                context.scene.GlobalVariable.image_previews[imageFilePathOnly].icon_id, scale=20)
```

The code above is the template_icon method I wrote.